# Which is fastest way to get 10 lines randomly inside a file with 10.000 lines?

Tags: php, performance, file, random, line

I have a file with ~ 10.000 lines inside. I want every time user access my website, it auto pick 10 lines randomly among them.
Code I currently used:

```
$filelog = 'items.txt';
$random_lines = (file_exists($filelog))? file($filelog) : array();
$random_count = count($random_lines);
$random_file_html = '';
if ($random_count > 10)
{
    $random_file_html = '<div><ul>';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    {
        $random_number = rand(0, $random_count - 1); // Duplicate are accepted
        $random_file_html .= '<li>'.$random_lines[$random_number]."</li>\r\n";
    }
    $random_file_html .= '</ul>
    </div>';
}
```

When I have < 1000 lines, every things is ok. But now, with 1000 lines. It make my website slow dow significantly.
That I'm thinking to other methods, like:

Divide file to 50 files, select randomly them, then select 10 lines randoms inside the selected file.
-- or --
I knew total lines (items). Make 10 numbers randomly, then read file use

```
$file = new SplFileObject('items.txt');
$file->seek($ranđom_number);
echo $file->current();
```

**(My server does not support any type of SQL)**

Maybe you have other methods that best suit for me. What is best method for my problem? Thank you very much!

Comment: How are you storing user data if there is no SQL?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way would be apparently **not** to pick 10 lines randomly out of a file with ~ 10.000 lines inside on every user's request.
It's impossible to answer more as we know no details of this "XY problem".

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to adjust the contents of the file then simply pad each of the lines so they have a common length. Then you can access the lines in the file using random access.

```
  $lineLength = 50; // this is the assumed length of each line

  $total = filesize($filename);
  $numLines = $total/$lineLength;

  // get ten random numbers
  $fp = fopen($filename, "r");
  for ($x = 0; $x < 10; $x++){
       fseek($fp, (rand(1, $numLines)-1)*$lineLength, SEEK_SET);
       echo fgets($fp, 50);
  }
  fclose($fp);
```

Comment: One don't need padding actually. But anyway, it's a rotten practice just by design. One should avoid such large data mining, not optimize it.

Comment: @YourCommonSense How would you get the same effect without padding the records? I agree that the problem is suspect but the way that the question was asked I believe this to be a performant solution.

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
$lines = file('YOUR_TXT_FILE.txt');
$rand  = array_rand($lines);

echo $lines[$rand];
```

for 10 of them just put it in a loop:

```
$lines = file('YOUR_TXT_FILE.txt');
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
   $rand = array_rand($lines);
   echo $lines[$rand];
}
```

**NOTE: ** the above code does not guarantee that **2** same lines wont be picked. In order to guarantee uniqueness you need to add extra while loop and an array that holds all randomly generated indexes, so next time it generates it and it already exists in an array, generate another one until its not in the array.

The above solution might not be fastest but might fulfill your needs. Since your server does not support any type of SQL, maybe switch to a different server? Because I am wondering how you are storing User Data? Are those stored in files also?

Comment: This is apparently the worst way possible.

Comment: well worse/better it answers the question. And why is it worse way would you like to elaborate on that?